# Direct conversion from YCbCr to CIE L* a* b*

Tags: yuv, color-space

I would like to convert a pixel value in YUV (YCbCr) to CIE L* a* b* color space. Do I have to go through RGB and CIEXYZ color space or do anyone know a formula for direct conversion?

Answer (score 4):

You need to go through each step. YCbCr is often encoded over video range (16-235/240 for 8 bit), and that needs to be converted to a XYZ using a particular Video RGB space definition(ie. Rec709 for High Def) which involves undoing the per-channel non-linearity of the RGB and then multiplying by the RGB->XYZ primary matrix. You then need to supply a white point (typically D65, the one in the RGB space definition), apply a different non-linearity and then another matrix to produce L*a*b*. I doubt there is much efficiency to be gained by combining all these into one transform.